# How to add the instrumentation key in Windows Dev Center Dashboard / Usage page to Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, uwp, windows-10-universal, azure-application-insights

I have published an app to Windows Store. Subscribed to Azure.

It seems I can only deploy/create new Application Insights resource.

How to add/link the instrumentation key found in Windows Dev Center App Analytics / Usage page to Azure Portal / Application Insights?

Comment: did you take a look here? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the standard getting started flow for Application Insights. Use the InstrumentationKey that the AI portal provides. Specify the iKey in the ApplicationInsights.config file. If the key is in the .config file, the Windows Dev Center should pick up the key as part of the ingestion / publishing process.

Comment: yes, if you want to get the full portal experience from dev center, you'll need to create your own AI resource, and supply *that* key in your project when you deploy it to the store.  if you do not provide a key in an `ApplicationInsights.config` file, the store assigns you one that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments indicated, you can use [these instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/) to add Application Insights Nuget to your application and insert the instrumentation key in code or in ApplicationInsights.config file.

However please note that while you can still use Application Insights for Windows Store apps, we are **recommending** that you onboard to [this Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.UWP/3.1.0-build08709) and start using [HockeyApp for Windows Store apps](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-windows-store-apps-and-windows-phone-store-apps):

Comment: Thank you for your input. However those instructions instruct how to create a new Application Insights resource. I am asking how to add existing instrumentation key found in Windows Dev Center App Usage page (auto created by Store?) to Azure Portal.

Comment: Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148557.aspx . 

"If you have associated an Azure subscription with the Visual Studio Application Insights SDK for your app, you can get more detailed app usage telemetry info in the Azure Portal. Links to your app's Azure Portal reports will be provided near the top of this report."

How to associate? Can not find any links?

Comment: Follow these instructions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17e3c839-9792-4fd0-b7ea-f12a44e080b4/application-insights-new-users-and-active-users-problem?forum=ApplicationInsights. Add Nuget package to your application and then specify your *existing* instrumentation key either in code or in ApplicationInsights.config.

Comment: The existing instrumentation key is in the ApplicationInsights.config. I am asking how to get the usage telemetry info in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Sorry, the link in my previous comment was incorrect. Correct link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/. To your question: you need to login to Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) with your live account. In the list of ApplicationInsights resources, there should be your resource. Is this what you're looking for or I not understanding the question?