# How to use the same Instrumentation Key in azure and dev center

Tags: azure, win-universal-app, azure-application-insights, windows-dev-center

Currently I have two Instrumentations Key, one in the Azure Application Insights, and another in the Windows Dev Center.

My ApplicationInsights.config has the Azure key so I don't see analytics in the dev center.

Is there anyway to change the Windows Dev Center key to the same as Azure, or vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192951/how-to-add-the-instrumentation-key-in-windows-dev-center-dashboard-usage-page/35229544#35229544

Comment: Thanks. I already did that but it was on a second release of my app, so the dev center had already assigned another key. I have the key in the .configs but Dev Center isn't picking it up =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue.
My ApplicationInsights.config was badly configured, it was missing the xmlns.
It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey> ...key here... </InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Instead, I had it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ApplicationInsights>
    <InstrumentationKey> ...key here... </InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```